# How to read numpy .npz file directly into C#

Tags: c#, python, numpy

I have a load of data files in numpy .npz format written from python.
I want to read them directly into C# for a few reasons.
The data files contain a number of 1D arrays of different types - some will by byte arrays, and other double arrays.
Can anyone give me some advice on how to achieve this?  Or otherwise what I might be doing wrong below?

I have tried using Accord.NET.NPZFormat but can't figure out how to make it work.  I think probably because you have to give it a type to return, and because the arrays are of different types it fails.
Here is a link to it:
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_IO_NpzFormat_Load__1.htm

I am struggling with syntax here, unsure of what to use as "T".  The closest I have got is with the following, but doesn't seem to have any data in the result.  Accord.IO has no example code.

```
public static void LoadNPZ(string zip_file, string npz_file)
{
  byte[] ret = new byte[0];
  using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(zip_file))
  {
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
    {
      if (entry.Name == npz_file + ".npz")
      {
        Stream fs = entry.Open();
        ret = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(ret, 0, (int)fs.Length);
      }
    }
  }
  if (ret.Length==0)
  {
    return;
  }

  var ret2 = NpzFormat.Load<object[]>(ret);
};
```

Comment: Do you have to use .npz? Or are you just needing a way to pull it into C#?

Comment: I just need a way to pull data from these .npz files into C#.  Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented the below answer in one of my projects that was previously using pickle. I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [NumSharp](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp) library.

Let say you have this data created in Python.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
single = arr.astype(np.single)
double = arr.astype(np.double)

np.savez('single.npz', data=single)
np.savez('double.npz', data=double)
```

The C# code to read them is below.

```
using NumSharp;

var singleContent = np.Load_Npz<float[]>("single.npz"); // type is NpzDictionary
var singleArray = singleContent["data.npy"]; // type is float[]

var doubleContent = np.Load_Npz<double[]>("double.npz"); // type is NpzDictionary
var doubleArray = doubleContent["data.npy"]; // type is double[]
```

If you don't specify name for your array then the default name is `arr_0`, and the C# code would be like this.

```
var singleArray = singleContent["arr_0.npy"];
var doubleArray = doubleContent["arr_0.npy"];
```

Note that NumSharp has the following limitation.

- The size of each dimension must be smaller than 2,147,483,591 bytes. Example: for integer (4 bytes), each dimension must have less than 536,870,898 elements.
- If you are using .NET Framework, the maximum array size is 2GB (all dimensions considered). On 64-bit platform this limit can be avoided by enabling the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` flag.

More information can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69978076/4510614) and this [blog post](https://duongnt.com/read-numpy-files-in-csharp/) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of both of them).

Comment: very useful. thanks

Comment: for large files i get the following exception. Any idea how to workaround it?
  Exception thrown: 'System.OverflowException' in NumSharp.dll 
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in NumSharp.dll
  Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: @SamerAamar: That is a limitation of NumSharp and array type in .NET. I edited my answer to remove the unnecessary conversion to NDArray and add a note about this limitation.

Answer (score -2):

I work with C# and python quite a bit, and my reccomendation is to create a COM Server

http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html

then in python you could simply have something like

```
import numpy as np

class NPtoCSharp:
    _reg_clsid_ = "{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}"
    _public_methods_ = ['load_file']

    _public_attrs_ = ['arr', 'the_file']

    _reg_desc_ = "Python NPZ Loader"

    _reg_progid_ = "NPtoCSharp"
    def __init__(self):

        self.arr = None
        self.the_file = None
    def load_file(self):

        self.arr = np.load(self.the_file)

        return self.arr
```

Then in C#

```
public void init_python()
{
    Type NPtoCSharp = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NPtoCSharp");
    NPtoCSharpInst = Activator.CreateInstance(NPtoCSharp);
    NPtoCSharpInst.the_file = 'myfile.npz';
}
```

Not complete but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: any chance you could add something on how to use the data inside the NPZ file after getting it into c#?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have since transitioned in to using a sqlite DB to store the array