# CSharp: Failed to read LARGE .npy file. Exception is "NumSharp.dll Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Tags: c#, numpy-ndarray, overflowexception, numsharp

I am trying to read a large .npy file in CSharp.
In order to do that i am trying to use the [NumSharp](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp) nuget.

The file is 7GB jagged float array (float[][]). It has ~1 million vectors, each vector is a 960 dimension.

**Note:**
To be more specific the data I use is the GIST from the following link [Approximate Nearest Neighbors Large datasets](http://corpus-texmex.irisa.fr/).

The following is the method I use to load the data but it failes with an exception:

```
    private static void ReadNpyVectorsFromFile(string pathPrefix, out List<float[]> candidates)
    {
        var npyFilename = @$"{pathPrefix}.npy";
        
        var v = np.load(npyFilename);//NDArray
        
        candidates = v
            .astype(np.float32)
            .ToJaggedArray<float>()
            .OfType<float[]>()
            .Select(a =>
            {
                return a.OfType<float>().ToArray();
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```

The exception is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.OverflowException' in NumSharp.dll An
> unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
> NumSharp.dll Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

How can I workaround this?

---

### Update

The NumSharp package has a limitation if the file is too big.
Read the comments/answers below for more explanations.
I added one answer with a suggestion for a workaround

However,
As a good alternative is to save the data as .npz (refer to: numpy.savez()) and then the following package can do the job:

https://github.com/matajoh/libnpy

Code sample:

```
        NPZInputStream npz = new NPZInputStream(npyFilename);
        var keys = npz.Keys();
        //var header = npz.Peek(keys[0]);
        var t = npz.ReadFloat32(keys[0]);

        Debug.Assert(t.DataType == DataType.FLOAT32);
```

Comment: Asking for recommendation of " _another package / nuget that i can use in CSharp to read a large .npy file_ " is off topic.

Comment: You could run the actual code in the repo and see why/where this happens

Comment: updated the question based on the comment from @user9938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the NumSharp data-structure is a heavy RAM consumer and it seems to be the CSharp GC is not aware of what NumSharp is allocating so it reaches the RAM limit very fast.

So,
In order to overcome this, I split the input npy file so that every part should not consume more than max memory allocation allowed in C# (2147483591). In my case i split into 5 different files (200k vectors each).

python part to split the large .npy file:

```
 infile = r'C:\temp\input\GIST.1m.npy'
 data = np.load(infile)

 # create 5 files
 incr = int(data.shape[0] / 5) 

 # the +1 is to handle any leftovers
 r = range(0,  int(size/incr + 1)) 

 for i in r:
    print(i)

    start = i * incr
    stop = min(start + incr, size)

    if(start >= len(data)):
        break

    np.save(infile.replace('.npy', f'.{i}.npy'), data[start:stop])
```

Now in CSharp the code looks as follows:

```
    private static void ReadNpyVectorsFromFile(string pathPrefix, out List<float[]> candidates)
    {
        candidates = new List<float[]>();

        // TODO: 
        // For now I am assuming there are 10 files maximum... 
        // this can be improved by scanning the input folder and 
        // collecting all the relevant files.
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(-1, 10))
        {
            var npyFilename = @$"{pathPrefix}.{i}.npy";
            Console.WriteLine(npyFilename);

            if (!File.Exists(npyFilename))
                continue;

            var v = np.load(npyFilename); //NDArray

            var tempList = v
                .astype(np.float32)
                .ToJaggedArray<float>()
                .OfType<float[]>()
                .Select(a => { return a.OfType<float>().ToArray(); })
                .ToList();

            candidates.AddRange(tempList);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've already found a workaround. Just in case you want to now the cause of your problem, it is because of a limitation of the `Array` class in .NET.

The `np.load(string path)` method is defined [here](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/blob/master/src/NumSharp.Core/APIs/np.load.cs#L16), which in turn calls `np.load(Stream stream)`.

```
int bytes;
Type type;
int[] shape;
if (!parseReader(reader, out bytes, out type, out shape))
    throw new FormatException();

Array array = Arrays.Create(type, shape.Aggregate((dims, dim) => dims * dim));

var result = new NDArray(readValueMatrix(reader, array, bytes, type, shape));
return result.reshape(shape);
```

Here, `bytes` is the size of your date type. Because you are using `float`, this value is `4`. And `shape` is the number of vectors and the shape of them.

Next, let's look at the `readValueMatrix` [method](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/blob/1fed94d2e556a7fdfc815775db68f9c8f195298a/src/NumSharp.Core/APIs/np.load.cs#L207).

```
int total = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < shape.Length; i++)
    total *= shape[i];
var buffer = new byte[bytes * total];
// omitted
```

NumSharp is trying to create a one-dimensional `byte` array with size equals `bytes * total`. Here, `bytes` is 4 and `total` is the number of vectors multiple by size of all dimensions.

However, in .NET, the maximum index in any given dimension of a `byte` array is `0X7FFFFFC7`, which is `2147483591`, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#remarks). I haven't downloaded your data yet, but my guess is it is big enough that `bytes * total > 2147483591`.

Note that if you want to use NumSharp to write you data back to npy file then you will have the same problem inside `writeValueMatrix` [method](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/blob/master/src/NumSharp.Core/APIs/np.save.cs#L81).